# Memory overhead when adding an object to a List directly vs. object creation

Tags: java

Is there a memory overhead when creating a Java object first, instead of adding it directly to a List or will the List automatically use the memory from the object, which is already allocated?

```
User user = new User(userID, username);
userList.add(user);
```

vs.

```
userList.add(new User(userID, username));
```

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: There is no difference at all. It is not clear what you mean with "will the `List` automatically use the memory from the object". When you add an object to a `List`, no new object is created or copied, no matter how you add it to the list.

Comment: Well the list has to save which elements are inside of it and at which position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no memory overhead. The extra reference to the list element (the `user` variable) resides on the stack. The first element of the list and the `user` variable reference the same object on the heap. In both cases there's a single memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

```
User user = new User(userID, username);
```

This line actually does two things. First it creates an object in memory (that's the right side of the =). After that, it creates a new variable called user and stores a reference to newly created object in it.

If you add it to the list then, the list will simply create another reference to the created object.

So in both cases, the object is only created once.

However, in the first case, you will create an additional variable (user). It's a reference though and not the object itself, so the memory it actually takes is basically nothing. And it's gone once the method you did this in finished anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's broadly the same thing. The memory allocation is done a single time in both cases.

The difference is that :
- in the first case, two references use the object. 
- In the second case, one reference uses the object.

Answer (score 0):

The object is not added to the list in either case. A *reference* to the object is added. The difference is only whether you intend to do something else with the object after adding it to the list. In the first case you still have the `user` variable referring to the object, so you can easily manipulate it further. In the latter case you don't have the variable, presumably you don't need to manipulate it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

1. There will not be any memory overhead as reference will be stored on stack.
2. But there will be negligible performance penalty  of creating extra reference variable which will be observed in case if someone tries to create it inside the for loop for very high value of n.

   ```
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>(size);
           for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
               User user = new User("User " + i, i);
               users.add(user);
           }
   ```